# Mysql full text returnig NULL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, myisam, full-text-indexing, mysql-5.5

My mysql code.

```
CREATE TABLE `videos` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `discription` text NOT NULL,
  `video_path` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `tumbnail_path` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `paid` int(250) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
INSERT INTO `videos` (`id`, `user_id`, `title`, `discription`, `video_path`, `tumbnail_path`, `paid`, `date`) VALUES
(1, 4, 'This is a new video', '<p>This is a new video from eduladder&nbsp;in at this video we are discribing how stuffs works</p>\r\n', 'uploadvid/xIdivzexFZXzr6bng2E9mU3PNvMVq0Iz.mp4', 'uploadthump/1AT1EsgJ--6iVLxEwEFRkWa9ADqqD1BG.jpg', 0, '2018-12-10'),
(2, 4, 'New Video for testig', '<p>This is a new video for testing purpose&nbsp;only</p>\r\n', 'uploadvid/_rsIHMc2giVoWV6aRixCoEUk0gKcDhDI.mp4', 'uploadthump/zA_t-2DMusUDvg9xVPwmRAn5-59He76-.jpg', 0, '2018-12-12'),
(3, 4, 'Some New Videos', '<p>This is a record of some new videos</p>\r\n', 'uploadvid/jPzlU3xSJaZVm7EzZu_JfaXq8kAK_1Vc.mp4', 'uploadthump/M_SZodSk20ba2FsXw3X1WVq7a48S_cj3.jpg', 0, '2018-12-13'),
(4, 4, 'Old video', '<p>This is an old video</p>\r\n', 'uploadvid/yaYiDBru2c7fCcosPmrj94JhZ5waxbu8.mp4', 'uploadthump/FhRXXen99DEa0d-8w5m2FDcvFyxlZgx4.png', 0, '2018-12-13'),
(5, 4, 'Almost new video and edited', '<p>This is about almost new video and editted&nbsp;version</p>\r\n', 'uploadvid/YOVPqiFO5xUnCtFAdYzgiY2wzsCnSQ11.mp4', 'uploadthump/MO1faxOKDNESee0gG5SQZYeantzlrPYM.png', 0, '2018-12-13');
ALTER TABLE `videos` ADD FULLTEXT(`title`,`discription`);
```

And the query which I am excecuting is here.

```
SELECT * , 
MATCH (title, discription) AGAINST ('New') AS score
FROM videos
WHERE MATCH (title, discription) AGAINST ('New')
ORDER BY score
DESC LIMIT 20
```

Here's a mysql fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jUs9EABZjuBL956WtnTbqx/3

But it is giving me nothing where am I going wrong how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with Full text Stop-words on the myisam engine, I changed the engine to InnoDB and I can get results.

See this link. [Full-Text Stopwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)

To fully disable stopwords, add this `ft_stopword_file = ''`, to your database configuration file, the repair the table to rebuild indexes,
`REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK`. and restart the server

Comment: Plz see the udated code https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jUs9EABZjuBL956WtnTbqx/3  innodb wont work it is myql version <5.6

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to disable stopwords, that should solve your issue on <5.6

Comment: I have added `ft_stopword_file = ''` to the my.conf file and restartted the mysql still the query returning none :(

Comment: Also can you please show the same on fiddle? I guess there might be some other ways to make this to work actually

Comment: Hmm, first i believe the file you need to edit ends with a .cnf and not .conf,
I have edited the answer futher

Comment: I have added the line to the file /etc/mysql/my.cnf then restartted mysql using sudo mysql restart then excicutted the query REPAIR TABLE videos QUICK i got the following out put in myadmin videos
repair
status
OK still it is not worki

Comment: Going through the mysql docs, it seems some other options could help.
Do the following again in order

add to .cnf file

`ft_stopword_file = '' ft_min_word_len=1 ft_stopword_file=''`, Restart the db server, run `REPAIR TABLE tbl_name QUICK.`

Comment: But it returning very few records where as in mysql 5.6 or greater ith Innodb it is returning more records

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185183/discussion-between-arun-vm-and-olubodun-agbalaya).

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for it to work with MySql 5.5 in your comment:

> Plz see the udated code db-fiddle.com/f/jUs9EABZjuBL956WtnTbqx/3
>   innodb wont work it is myql version <5.6

Then it's 2 different case. For MySql 5.7, Stopword list applies only.

But for MySql 5.5 from your latest fiddle here are the 2 reasons :

The 1st reason this is not working is because the word you are searching for is present in 50% or more of the total rows, so it is considered as `Common Word` and won't match as a result. See the [Mysql 5.5 FullText Search Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) :

> There are three types of full-text searches:
>
> A natural language search interprets the search string as a phrase in
>   natural human language (a phrase in free text). There are no special
>   operators, with the exception of double quote (") characters. The
>   stopword list applies. In addition, words that are present in 50% or
>   more of the rows are considered common and do not match.

And the 2nd one is because by default the FullText Search Length is set to 4. So you need to change it in `my.cnf` and add value :

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len = 3
```

to be able to search 3 characters words.

But since in db-fiddle I cannot modified the length, here is a [modified working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jUs9EABZjuBL956WtnTbqx/4) where the word `Older` is used. `Older` is not present on 50% of rows and its length is `>= 4`.